# utilising ipsative measures

Tags: multivariate-analysis, ranks

I am using a data set containing ipsative measures resulting from forced ranks. For example, respondents are asked to rank in terms of importance various methods of employee development (training, learning from each other, trial and error).

```
id resp   Training Learneach trialerr
1           1          2       3
2           3          1       2
3           2          3       1
4           3          2       1
```

The answers are not meant to form a scale (so I am not trying to recover an underlying latent variable).
I have 2 problems:

1. How can such variables be used as independent variables in a regression? The three variables suffer from the constant-sum problem (the three variables add up to 6, they are multicollinear). Leaving one out would not solve the problem because the coefficients on the remaining 2 variables will be difficult to interpret.
2. A second set of variables contains the ranking (in terms of importance) of various product market strategies (price, quality, customisation, innovation). I want to use these variables as dependent variables. How should such variables be analysed? I thought of using a multivariate ordered probit model (4 equations, one ordered probit for each strategy) allowing for correlated residuals. The intuition is that what moves one strategy up the ranks must move the other strategies down the ranks. However, I have not find anything in the literature confirming this intuition. So, I am open to alternatives.

Has anybody had any experience in using ranks as dependent and independent variables? Can anybody point to relevant literature?

Thank you for your help.

Giovanni